# Handling a task after a Fragment Loads

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment, android-lifecycle

My little learning project here is a simple note taking app that uses dynamic fragments to save notes. I'm having an issue when it comes to displaying loaded text from a ".txt" file into a TextView.

Debugging shows that when I go to find my **NoteEditFragment**, it is null. This is likely the reason my file isn't correctly being translated into the TextView. How do I go about invoking my NoteEditFragment's setText function only after the Fragment comes into existence? Is there a better way to do this? I'm trying to keep fragments only handling UI and use my Activity as more of a presenter.

The sequence that doesn't work:

```
//Interfaces
override fun noteEditSaveClicked(note: String) {
        saveNote(note)
        swapFragments()
        openNote()
    }
```

The sequence that works (likely because it waits until the Fragment is loaded)

```
   override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        openNote()
    }
```

Complete Activity Code:

```
package com.inviscidlabs.kotlinnotes

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_note_home.*
import java.io.File

class NoteHome : NoteHomeFragmentEvent, NoteEditAction, AppCompatActivity() {


//Lifecycle
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_home)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        swapFragments()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        openNote()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_note_home, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

//Local Functions
    private fun openNote(){
        var printText = ""

        File(this.filesDir, "note.txt").bufferedReader().forEachLine { line ->
            printText += line
        }

        val f: NoteHomeFragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentIDs.HOME.fragID) as NoteHomeFragment?
        f?.setNote(printText)

    }

    private fun swapFragments() {
        val replaceFragment = { frag: Fragment, fragTag: String ->
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.anh_fragContainer,
                    frag, fragTag).commit()
        }

        if (supportFragmentManager.fragments.size > 0) {
            if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentIDs.NOTEEDIT.fragID) == null) {
                replaceFragment(NoteEditFragment(), FragmentIDs.NOTEEDIT.fragID)
            } else {
                replaceFragment(NoteHomeFragment(), FragmentIDs.HOME.fragID)
                openNote()
            }
        } else {
            replaceFragment(NoteHomeFragment(), FragmentIDs.HOME.fragID)
            openNote()
        }
    }

    fun saveNote(noteBody: String){
        File(this.filesDir, "note.txt").bufferedWriter().use { out ->
            out.write(noteBody)
        }
    }


//Interfaces
    override fun noteEditSaveClicked(note: String) {
            saveNote(note)
            swapFragments()
            openNote()
        }

    override fun addNoteFabClicked() { swapFragments()}

}

enum class FragmentIDs (val fragID: String){
    NOTEEDIT("NoteEditFragment"), HOME("NoteHomeFragment")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is not immediately available in on created because it has its own process for going through. If you want to maintain a presenter structure, you should create a companion presenter object for the fragment to coordinate the fragment rather than controlling it via Activity.